# Best Practice of using nested constant variable across project in Golang?

Tags: dictionary, go

In NodeJS, when we want to declare some constant variable and would like them to be used across the project, we might write something like:

```js
// const.js
module.exports.mqttQOS = {
    AtMostOnce:  0,
    AtLeastOnce: 1,
    ExactlyOnce: 2,
};
```

Therefore, we could use it like `constant.mqttQOS.AtMostOnce`, and throw an error when we use `constantQOS.ErrorRefering`.

In Golang we could only do something like:

```golang
var mqttQoS = map[string]byte{
    "AtMostOnce":  0,
    "AtLeastOnce": 1,
    "ExactlyOnce": 2,
}
```

And use it as: `fmt.Println(mqttQoS["AtMostOnce"]) // print: 0`

However, it'll print `fmt.Println(mqttQoS["ErrorRefering"]) // print: 0` because of the characteristic of Golang map (like Python's defaultdict() )

Althought we could do something to prevent this error referring by:

```golang
var mqttQoS = map[string]byte{
    "AtMostOnce":  0,
    "AtLeastOnce": 1,
    "ExactlyOnce": 2,
}
result, ok := mqttQoS["ErrorRefering"]
if ok {
    fmt.Println("value: ", result)
}
```

So back to my question, other than using `ok` to limit the error referring,
**is there any better practice to work on the nested constant objects in Golang?**

Updated:
so that I could use like `mqttQoS.AtMostOnce` and will raise an error when I `mqttQos.ErrorRefer`.

Defining another `type` is one way, but is it common practice in big projects?

Thanks!

Comment: *"is there any better practice to work on the constant objects in Golang?"* Yes, use normal constnats, i.e. use the `const` keyword to declare them and do not use maps as "constants". If you must, you can declare the constants in their own package. Referencing a constant that was not declared will fail at compile time.

Comment: For more: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations and https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants. Also take a look at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota

Comment: Thanks for your comment, for sure I understand `const`, `iota`, and how to declare and use them.
Working on the big project, you may want to manage all of the constant variables in one file. And in some cases, you would also want to have some constant variables which contain another constant variable as I provide in the NodeJS example above.
What is the best practice to have this effect in Go? Or Go didn't recommend this way of managing constant var.

Comment: There's no recommendation for nested pseudo constants. If you want nested variables that "blow up" when incorrectly referenced you can use a struct, nested as deep as you want it to be. It's also typed per-variable (field) unlike a map.

Comment: "Constant variable" is an oxymoron. Pick one. Go does not support constant composite types, such as structs or maps. It is not normal to use constants by default as appears to be the case in JavaScript nowadays (I never understood that practice, to be honest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referred to the comments, using nested const is not the common practice in Golang.

`constant literal` might be the solution to the question.

There are related discussions and proposals on github.com/golang

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21130